# IE7 & IE8 does not trigger onsubmit javascript *before* submittion

Tags: javascript, forms, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, submit

I have a search form:

```
<form class="searchForm" id="topSearchForm" action="/search.ds">
```

that has an onsubmit-event attached to it, triggering a javascript. The purpose of this javascript is to empty certain form-fields before submission of the form based on certain criteria.

To be clear, what needs to happend is:

> User input -> User clicks search button (or presses "enter") -> Javascript runs -> fields are cleared -> form is submitted

This works exactly as intended in all browsers *except* in IE7 and IE8. The javascript runs but for some reason the form submission is done *before* the fields are being cleared by the javascript. This causes the submitted page to include the data from fields that were supposed to be cleared.

I only have control of (certain parts of) the UI and cannot handle anything after the submission of the form. For usability purpose it is important that these fields (that should be cleared) are filled out up until the user submits the form.

Why is the internal logic different in IE7 & IE8 (it works fine in IE9 and "all other browsers)? Is there a way for me to circumvent this issue?

Here are some more code to clarify:

I attach the event to the form:

```
var formElement = document.getElementById("topSearchForm");
[...]
formElement.attachEvent('onsubmit', function() {clearForSubmit()});
```

and clearForSubmit is defined and *is* triggered.

Comment: can you post some code so we can see what you used please

Comment: Done, but the code *does* work, the problem is the call ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this in the js

```
<form onsubmit="clearForSubmit(); return false;">
```

this will NOT submit the form, you can submit the form after you clear it with

```
form_name.submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an `onclick` event instead of `onsubmit`, then submit the form at the end of the function in code.

Comment: Will the onclick prevent the submit event propagation? How will I "submit the form at the end of the function"?